# Wearing hats and Jackets

Tags: clothing, chabad, black-hats

I have heard lots of "anecdotal evidence" (which means Mashpiyim telling over what they heard at private Yechidusim [private audiences]) that the Lubavitcher Rebbe wanted people (or Bochurim) to wear hats and jackets.

Is there any "written" source for this statement (such as a Sicha (even non-Muga) Letter, etc.)

Comment: What are yechidusim?

Comment: @DoubleAA private audiences.

Comment: @DoubleAA, they're _y'chiduyos_.

Comment: Why would this be a chidush?  We've been wearing hats and jackets for centuries.

Comment: @yoel But not millennia.

Comment: @DoubleAA arguable!  Look at last week's parsha.  A turban and robe look suspiciously like a hat and jacket to me...

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I apologize, it was'nt clear to me. I think the inyan is that a Chasid needs to look like a Jew and wearing a hat and jacket separates a person from the rest of the world in this respect.

Comment: I think there are sichot of the Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe where he talks about how bochurim should dress.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill: hence the comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a question for here, or [Skeptics.SE]. While it is a question do with Judaism, it is a question that is asking to prove, or disspove a claim, which is [Skeptics.SE]' scope

Comment: @Ephraim the crowd there would not be able to answer this question, and we have plenty of [such questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources-mekorot)

Comment: @Ephraim, Shmuel's right. No need to engage in [scope gerrymandering](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About hats, the Rebbe comments in a footnote to one of his letters ([Igros Kodesh, letter 3356](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/10/3356), and from there in [Sefer Haminhagim, p. 9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30479&pgnum=17)) that it is normative chassidic practice to wear a double headcovering - a yarmulka under one's hat. (As R' Y.S. Ginsburg points out ([Hiskashrus, no. 537](http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?CategoryID=532&ArticleID=1474)), this formulation fits with the older European (and American) practice that everyone wore a hat anyway, so that the yarmulka was the "extra" covering; whereas nowadays we think of wearing a hat as something additional.)

R' Ginsburg notes, though, that this doesn't necessarily mean that one has to wear a hat all the time; indeed, the Rebbe himself, when studying privately, often did so wearing only a yarmulka.

Not sure about sources for jackets.

---

Looking in R. Michoel Seligson's new index of the Rebbe's talks and writings (highly recommended, btw), he references (under בגד) an account from 5729, printed in from Kfar Chabad magazine #700, about an elder chassid who put on a hat and jacket before opening the door for the Merkos shluchim; the Rebbe commented, when hearing this, that this chassid may be "[physically] far away, yet [spiritually] very near."

Comment: At least half an answer :)

Comment: page 223 of Kulam Bechachma vol 2 - http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=BSgRAQAAIAAJ&q=%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94&dq=%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r_P4T9C5Iujj0QGhovTOBg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA - has a story (no source given) which illustrates the idea that the kippah is the second covering. I'll translate it here: A Maskil came to the Chassid R' Chaim Leib of Sosnitz (a Chassid of the Tzemach Tzedek) with a question. "Tell me, my teacher, what is the reason why chassidim and men of action cover their head with a hat and a...

Comment: ...kippah underneath it? Is it not enough for a jewish person to wear only a hat, like everyone else (K'Derech HaBri'ot)?" "Go see," answered R' Chaim Leib, "a person in his house has has a ceiling and a roof above his head, while an animal in a barn has only a roof above its head."

Comment: @Alex Do you have any information e.g. a title for this index