# Hasidim's (lack of) hats

Tags: minhag, chasidut-hasidism, black-hats

I heard that hasadim put on black hat but I also see some not putting; what are their differences?

Comment: I heard an idea from a respected man that unmarried men put on hats (but he might have a litvish point of view) married men use the talles as the head covering

Comment: in what context?

Comment: Can you clarify "black hat"? Many Jews who wear black hats, i.e., Borsalinos, or other fedoras, are actually "yeshivish" not Hassidim. The only Hassidic sect that I know of that wears fedoras is Chaba"d. Almost all the rest wear shtreimls, spodeks, etc. and almost exclusively on Shabbat and Yom Tov. Technically, most shtreimls would be considered black hats (they are hats and they are black.)

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15081/5275 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28281/5275

Comment: What sort of Hassidim did you see not wearing them, and in what context did you see this?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for.  D0 you mean to ask the differences between Hasidim who wear hats, and those who don't, or do you mean to ask why some don't wear hats?

Answer (score 0):

**All Haredi Jews have hats.** But not all of them wear it all the time. Wearing a hat is customary, not obligatory (as Kipah) to all Haredi Jews, it is a sign of respect. The more respectful a Torah scholar is, the more he wears it (all sorts of hats).

The order is as following: Shabbos davening (Maariv and Mincha) - all Haredis do that, weekday davening - most Haredis, Shabbos showing in public - most, weekday showing in public - less, depending on one's occupation.